# Deriving equations of Epipolar lines for linear array scanners?

Tags: photogrammetry

I'm going to obtain the equations of the Epipolar lines of a given image captured with linear array scanners. There are some papers addressed this subject, but they haven't stated key points in detail, and thus I'm not able to implement the equations properly. Therefore, I need a pseudo code listing all the procedures step by step. 
Can someone suggest me the steps of the Epipolar line extraction for linear array scanners?

The links of the papers are as follows:

http://asprs.org/a/publications/pers/2000journal/august/2000_aug_961-966.pdf

http://www.ipi.uni-hannover.de/fileadmin/institut/pdf/ono.pdf

Comment: please add the links of the papers you have found so far

Comment: Please **edit** the question in response to comments for clarification.  It's not fair to those who would answer your question to have to scan comments for critical details.

Comment: Thank you Sepideh. These are the links of the papers: http://www.ipi.uni-hannover.de/fileadmin/institut/pdf/ono.pdf  and  http://asprs.org/a/publications/pers/2000journal/august/2000_aug_961-966.pdf

Comment: I've already found [this paper](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.1477-9730.2005.00303.x/abstract?userIsAuthenticated=false&deniedAccessCustomisedMessage=) that I think is more detail-oriented and relevant that the one's that you addressed. But maybe I can help more the next days through asking this question from one of my professors.

Comment: search for key words like "toutin", "ayman f.habib" and "morgan" for the authors. another keyword is "cardinal functions". because insuch images because of the large number of unknowns you're forced to use cardinal functions and reduce the number of unknowns.

Comment: [This proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/90327/remote-sensing-and-photogrammetry) is supposed to be a Q&A community for questions just like yours

Answer (score 1):

This is [Michel Morgan's dissertation](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?cluster=4546905958304801012&hl=en&as_sdt=0,5) which is available online from the university of Calgary. It's all about what you want.

Your questions are not considered to be common professional questions in photogrammetry community. They are challenging, academic and need a lot of search.

Take this as an advice and try to expand your searching abilities. I can search for you but this way, I'll give you just a fish and won't teach you fishing -Iranian proverb, I don't know what is the equivalent in English :)

No one will give up his time to search instead of you in Q&A communities. I just searched because this was interesting for me. People rarely get engaged with just a single question.

For success in academic life, you need to be a good searcher not just a good questioner and nowadays online searching is the key part of searching.

When encountering with such academic questions (not common professional questions like working with a specific software, etc)

1. Try to search in [scholar.google.com](http://scholar.google.com) not in [google.com](http://google.com)
2. Try to use good keywords (This is a skill you will learn by experience and in time)
3. another resource can be [books.google.com](http://books.google.com)
4. when you are searching for lecture notes or pieces of code on [google.com](http://google.com), paste their URL on the top of your browser and manipulate it a bit to access other parts of the FTP. Maybe you can find better material.
5. When you find a paper that you think is somehow related but not very related to your search topic, have a look at the paper's references and citations. maybe you could find a good resource among them.
6. Try to get familiar with major journals in your field and search in the journal's site. [here's a list of remote sensing journals](https://sites.google.com/site/sepidehabadpour9069/remote-sensing-journals). Try to have such list for your own field of study.
7. Get familiar with scientific databases like science direct, scopus, IEEE, etc and use them in your search
8. At last if you couldn't find a very good resource, **ask a comprehensive question here and include your search results so far to give others a clue to help you**

These were just some techniques that I had in mind and I'm learning as a student. If you do search yourself, you will find better techniques to be a good searcher.

Comment: Thank you Sepideh. I have already read the Morgan's dissertation (four months ago!). Further, those papers were also mentioned in the dissertation, and I got their titles from that. The problem is that I have to implement one of the two methods proposed in those papers, not Morgan's dissertation. Apart from this subject, it's worth noting that I'm a programmer and design search engines and am very familiar with searching and other stuff. I also can suggest you much more techniques than those you listed above for searching.

Comment: Then you didn't say such thing that you have to implement one of those papers. Anyway if you want to implement them, you should have knowledge in photogrammetry as well as being a programmer

Comment: @Federico please edit your original post and include that you are not just searching for methods and you should implement one of those papers. **Start and study one of your papers and then ask detailed questions about each specific step of the algorithms that you don't understand.** This way you can gradually extract the full pseudo code of the algorithm.